# Making member function, friend of a class

Tags: c++, class, private, friend

I've been trying to write up a code to implement a member function that could access private data of a class by declaring it as a friend within the class. But my code is failing and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A;
class B
{
    private:
    int b;       // This is to be accessed by member function of A

    public:
    friend void A::accessB();
};

class A
{
    private:
    int a;

    public:
    void accessB();
};

void A::accessB()
 {
     B y;
     y.b = 100;
     cout << "Done" << endl;
 }

int main(void)
{
    A x;
    x.accessB();
}
```

I am trying to access the private contents of B making use of **getAccessB** function which is member function of A. I have declared it as a friend. What's wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't work with a forward declaration, in this case the complete declaration of `A` must be seen, or you declare `friend A;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A::accessB` is not declared at the point of the `friend` declaration, so you can't refer to it. You can fix this by shifting the order of definitions and declarations such that `A::accessB` is visible to `B`:

```
class A
{
    private:
    int a;

    public:
    void accessB();
};

class B
{
    private:
    int b;

    public:
    friend void A::accessB();
};


void A::accessB()
 {
     B y;
     y.b = 100;
     cout << "Done" << endl;
 }
```

Note that making a function a `friend` just so that it can modify your private state is a bad code smell. Hopefully you are just doing this to understand the concepts.

Comment: Just one more thing. I think I got it. There's just one little confusion. If I move A::accessB() above class B in the code you have posted in your answer, then the code doesn't work. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because `A::accessB()` declares a variable of type `B`, which hasn't been defined yet. A forward declaration won't work there because `B` needs to be a complete type.

Comment: Why B needs to be a complete type? What's the general rule to follow to determine if forward declaration would work or not?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration) for what you can and can't do with forward declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering. If you are referring to `A::accessB`, `A` must be declared by that point. Place the `A` class above the `B`, and it will work fine.